# Sum of MEX of all subarrays of the given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, segment-tree

> Find the sum of MEX of all subarrays of the given array. The MEX
> (minimum excluded) of an array is the smallest non-negative integer
> that does not belong to the array.
>
> For instance: The MEX of [2,2,1] is
> 0, because 0 does not belong to the array. The MEX of [3,1,0,1] is 2,
> because 0 and 1 belong to the array, but 2 does not. The MEX of
> [0,3,1,2] is 4 because 0, 1, 2 and 3 belong to the array, but 4 does
> not. It's worth mentioning that the MEX of an array of length n is
> always between 0 and n inclusive.
>
> Constraints:
> n<=10^5,a[i]<=n

> I thought of a O(n^2) solutions which will not pass the given constraints. We need to find a O(nlogn) or O(n) solution

Comment: What is your O(n^2) solution?

Comment: Solution is available online: https://codedrills.io/problems/subarray-mex-sum

Comment: Yes, i went through this solution but it seems a bit difficult to understand. Can this problem can be done using dp or something?

Answer (score 0):

The MEX (minimum excluded) of an array is the smallest non-negative integer that does not belong to the array. For instance:

The MEX of [2,2,1] is 0, because 0 does not belong to the array.
The MEX of [3,1,0,1] is 2, because 0 and 1 belong to the array, but 2 does not.
The MEX of [0,3,1,2] is 4 because 0,1,2 and 3 belong to the array, but 4 does not.
Find the maximum possible MEX of an array of non-negative integers such that the bitwise OR of the elements in the array does not exceed X.